# How to create Line with different colors

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am making some "statistical" Analysis over different Videos and Images. It´s Histogram-like over every Frame. In each Frame I take 16 prededefined Colors and rate them.

I am drawing Lines (up to down) into an Canvas where every Line can consist of that 16 colors in different intensities. For every Frame there is an new Line in the Canvas.

My Question:

1.) How can I draw Lines with different colors? So far I only came up that I draw an Part of the Line with an specified color then (if needed) draw again from the last point of that Line an new Subline with an new Color. So, in worst case I do that 16 times for one Line. How can I do that more easily?

2.) How can I apply some kind of "intensity" (brighter/darker) to that colors?

3.) Since it´s possible that I have to draw 100.000+ Lines for one Video, what can I do in order to speed up draw time and save memory? (well, at least I guess that that will take some time, I have no code so far and can only assume that...). Would it be an good approach to "precompute" every Line an save that somewhere and when it´s needed to pop it into the Canvas?

Comment: In addition to the line-segment approach, you can create linear-gradients and fill the 1 pixel wide strips with these gradients. I think it would probably be clearer (and shorter) to write code to draw a series of line segments, rather than fill a single rect with a gradient, but it is an another approach. You can see more about linear gradients here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_createlineargradient.asp

Comment: Hmm I see, With Gradients, is it even possible to draw them with one pixel accuracy? What would be the benefit if I use many methods to draw that Sublines, I only knew at Runtime how long they will be and how to combine them.

Answer (score 1):

1. Html5 lines are drawn using path commands beginning with `context.beginPath`. You can draw multiple line segments with a single set of line path commands but each single set can only have one style (== one color). Your workaround (as you suspected) will be to issue a separate `beginPath` command for each desired colored line segment.
2. Html5 colors default to the RGBA color format, but you can also use the HSLA color format. This way you can change your "L" value to lighten or darken your hue. (The hue, "H", is basically your color).
3. Optimizing your line drawings is very dependent on the conditions in your own app. If the lines require significant processing to determine their position, color or other styling then you might (or might not) gain performance by pre-calculating those line values. On balance, canvas draws path commands (lines) very, very quickly so I would certainly start by test drawing your lines "live" to see if the canvas can keep up.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: Yes. you are right! I am going to care about performance when I got problems with it, I just like to consider stuff like that before...    So there is really no way to color Lines in different colors? That seems strange to me, thinking how nice Canvas is.. I have found [link](http://html5tutorial.com/advanced-path-painting/#beginPath) and don´t get why stroke takes the last color, although an different one was applied to another SubPath.

Comment: Yep, A single path containing multiple line segments can only have 1 color--no more. You'll have to do multiple paths (==multiple beginPath's).  It may not apply, but if you have 2+ line segments that are assigned the same color, you can draw those segments in one path since they share a common color: https://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/90yg69ec/